# .htaccess two directives cause Unexpected Token <

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I got two pages that handle the params and display relative pages, first is the auth route and default route.

```
http://example.com/auth/login
http://example.com/dashboard
```

First is handled by page auth.php and param page (EG: http://example.com/auth.php?page=login). The second is handled by index.php and param page (EG: http://example.com/index.php?page=dashboard).

I've made the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!index.php).+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^auth/([^/]*)$ /auth.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But this cause all my Javascripts assets make the error 'Unexpected token <' in the auth section and fail to load, so I got a plain text page without js and css. The problem seems to be related to the first directive, commenting this I can reach the Auth page and assets work fine

Since I'm using C9IDE, I can't access full errors file, Apache2 wrote only this, related to server start:

```
[Thu Jan 26 20:31:04.795013 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7163] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jan 26 20:31:04.795100 2017] [core:notice] [pid 7163] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2'
```

Comment: `Unexpected token <` possibly means you are getting an HTML error page. You can (and should) check the actual contents sent by server.

Comment: _Every_ request that matches the pattern gets rewritten to index.php. So either your index.php must handle delivering of JS and CSS resources as well, or you need to exclude those from being rewritten. This is usually done using RewriteCond to exclude files or folders that actually exist in the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, if the problem you see is caused by this, but the order of the rules is important.

The first rule already captures everything, including requests for `/auth`. The second rule is then never triggered, because requests for `auth` are already rewritten to `/index.php?page=auth/...`.

When you swap the rules to

```
RewriteRule ^auth/([^/]*)$ /auth.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index.php).+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

the "auth" rule has a chance to rewrite auth requests. But even then, these rewritten (auth.php) requests are again swallowed by the "index" rule and rewritten to `/index.php?page=auth.php`.

---

To fix this, you shouldn't rely on the [`negative lookahead`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but rather use a [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to filter "real" files, like `index.php`, `auth.php` or any CSS or Javascript files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^auth/([^/]*)$ /auth.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

These rules (plus conditions) ignore real files, and process only requests, which are not files `!-f` and not directories `!-d`. Again see [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for details.